# How to access config/env/all.js data in a client controller?

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I have some configuration values(numbers) that I need while doing some computation in the angular code in the client controller. I general, how can one access the serverside config data in the clientside code?
If note is it possible to have a config file/folder in the public folder and easily access using angular code in client controller?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for here, but you have basically 3 options to handle this.

**Expose An API Endpoint**

You should be able to simply create an API endpoint to read the config data on the server and send it down to the client as JSON. Then you could access it in Angular like so:

```
$http.get('/api/config')
   .success(function(configData){
      //Do something with config data
   });
```

**Expose Config File Publicly**

> **Warning** - This may not be wise if your config contains sensitive data such as connection strings.

If you have a `.json` or a `.xml` file on the server with this info, then you could just make it available to HTTP GET requests and then the same code as above would apply. With the exception that if it is XML you will need to add a transform to parse the data.

```
$http.get('/config.json')
   .success(function(configData){
      //Do something with config data
   });
```

**Embed Config As Angular Constant/Value**

> **Note** - This won't work if your data is dynamic on the server.

An even simpler way is to simply put your configuration into a `.js` file and register it with Angular as a constant or a value.

```
angular.module('myModule')
   .constant('config', {
      foo:'bar',
      blah:123
   });
```

This way you can simply inject that anywhere in your app that you need access to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing so many solutions. I think the third solution suits me the best as it is a bunch of string constants that I want to access across the client views.